# How to make CKeditor format code indenting elements and adding line breaks?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

Using CKEditor in Drupal 7, I could configure CKEditor to format the code adding line breaks and indenting the HTML code automatically.

For example, pasting this in the source code:

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">Test</div></div>
```

CKEditor could be configured to turn it into:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

To achieve that, I just had to select the right configuration for CKEditor (Indent the element contents, Break line before the opening tag,  Break line after the closing tag), and include the Javascript configuration:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

But in Drupal 8, I can't see those options and CKEditor removes all the whitespace from the source code.

How can I make CKEditor work like with that configuration in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, thanks to the post [CKEditor with well-formatted html source code](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20996/ckeditor-with-well-formatted-html-source-code).

I just added to a custom module the following code:

```
function mymodule_editor_js_settings_alter(array &$settings) {
  foreach (array_keys($settings['editor']['formats']) as $text_format_id) {
    if ($settings['editor']['formats'][$text_format_id]['editor'] === 'ckeditor') {          
      $settings['editor']['formats'][$text_format_id]['editorSettings']['customConfig'] = base_path() . drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/ckeditor_config.js';           
    }
  }        
}
```

to include a configuration a file called ckeditor_config.js that contains the code:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
    // Sets indentation of source code
    ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'div', {
                indent: true,
                breakBeforeOpen: true,
                breakAfterOpen: true,
                breakBeforeClose: true,
                breakAfterClose: true
            });
});
```

Doing this, CKEditor will keep the indentations in the source code, and a well formatted code easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you're using CKeditor in your body field.

Ideally, you shouldn't be adding classes/wrappers in CKeditor. You should use the node template file of your content type and add them there.

Go to your theme's template folder and create a copy of **node.html.twig** and rename the copy to **node--[content-type-name].html.twig**. Ex: node--article.html.twig, if it's the article content type.

Inside this twig file, find where it says `{{ content }}` and delete that. Instead, you put `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">{{ content.body }}</div></div>`

and print other fields `{{ content.field_name }}` that you need.

Clear/Flush the cache to see changes.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense, but some people are going to want to do this. I would advise the CKEditor plugin for Bootstrap and just integrate them - but most of them are not free. That way it isn't just hidden markup, it is a bit more defined. But generally, you don't want a WYSIWYG to determine layout and markup.

Comment: @kevin no you don't. What if the article/content writer does not know html and removes the markup?

Comment: You wouldn't believe how many people have the requirement for this. It's ridiculous but sometimes unavoidable. Example: http://ckeditor.com/addon/widgetbootstrap

Comment: @Kevin interesting, I've been using the [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module instead of that and then adding the boostrap markup to the paragraphs template file.

Comment: @NoSssweat maybe it's not very common but I think it makes sense, that's why the Drupal 7 module has those options. It's not only about bootstrap, that was just an example, what I want is to have a clean code with its proper indentations, but right now when I paste the code and save the node all the indentations are removed.

Is there a way to get this in the Drupal 8 version?

BTW I didn't know the paragraphs module, I'll have a look at it too.

Comment: @jmzea checkout this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqtCv7KEUis) to see how paragraphs works.

Comment: Thank you @NoSssweat, Paragraphs it's an amazing module.